# Python: How to groupby one column and then calculate a trailing mean and cumulative count where current start date is after prior end date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to groupby one column (for example, 'country'). Each row has an associated 'start_date' and 'end_date'. For every row in the groupby, I want to increment the counter if the 'start_date' in the current row occurs after the most recent 'end_date' in the prior rows (and not increment otherwise). I want the same logic to apply to the trailing mean. I have sorted by country and start_date.

For example, I have a dataframe that can be generated with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# create df
data = {'country': ['arg', 'arg', 'arg', 'arg', 'arg', 'usa', 'usa', 'usa'],
        'start_date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-05-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-07-01',
                       '2020-03-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-09-01'],
        'end_date': ['2020-10-01', '2020-09-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-06-01', '2021-12-01',
                     '2020-10-01', '2020-08-01', '2021-05-01'],
        'value': [250, 300, 150, 170, 200, 150, 100, 120]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And the desired result (with the new columns trailing_mean and count) would be:

| country | start_date | end_date | value | trailing_mean | counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| arg | 2020-01-01 | 2020-10-01 | 250 | NA | 0 |
| arg | 2020-01-01 | 2020-09-01 | 300 | NA | 0 |
| arg | 2020-05-01 | 2021-01-01 | 150 | NA | 0 |
| arg | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-01 | 170 | 233.33 | 3 |
| arg | 2021-07-01 | 2021-12-01 | 200 | 217.5 | 4 |
| usa | 2020-03-01 | 2020-10-01 | 150 | NA | 0 |
| usa | 2020-05-01 | 2020-08-01 | 100 | NA | 0 |
| usa | 2020-09-01 | 2021-05-01 | 120 | 100 | 1 |

Notice how the trailing_mean is NA until there are records that have a start_date that occurs AFTER the end_date. On every record, the trailing mean only takes into account past records that have already completed (their end_date happens before the current record's start_date). This is the same logic for the counter. It is 0 and then it increments. It jumps from 0 to 3 because all three prior rows ended before that row has started

I have tried to groupby country and iterate through the rows. But I am having trouble accounting for the differences in end_dates. You can't just look back at the prior row you have to look at all prior records because the end_dates are not sequential

Comment: When you say "most recent end_date", do you mean the value in the previous row for that country or the most recent of *all* the end_date values for that country up to that point or the value associated with the most recent start_date for that country up to that point?

Comment: The most recent of all the end_date values for that country. So the counter and trailing_mean should increase for every time there is a start_date that occurs after a prior record (or records) end_date

Comment: So for USA, in the third row the start_date is `2020-09-01`, but that is not after `2020-10-01`  in the first row so why does it get a trailing average?

Comment: Because it is after the 2020-08-01 in the second usa row and the trailing average and counter is looking at all previous records in a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) a custom function to generate your counts and trailing means for each group:

```py
def count_and_avg(df):
    mask = [df['end_date'] < start for start in df['start_date']]
    df = df.assign(count=[sum(m) for m in mask],
                   trailing_mean=[df[m]['value'].sum() / sum(m) if sum(m) else 0 for m in mask]
                   )
    return df

out = df.groupby('country').apply(count_and_avg).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
  country  start_date    end_date  value  count  trailing_mean
0     arg  2020-01-01  2020-10-01    250      0       0.000000
1     arg  2020-01-01  2020-09-01    300      0       0.000000
2     arg  2020-05-01  2021-01-01    150      0       0.000000
3     arg  2021-05-01  2021-06-01    170      3     233.333333
4     arg  2021-07-01  2021-12-01    200      4     217.500000
5     usa  2020-03-01  2020-10-01    150      0       0.000000
6     usa  2020-05-01  2020-08-01    100      0       0.000000
7     usa  2020-09-01  2021-05-01    120      1     100.000000
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but this solves my problem. I was close to implementing what you did, but your function works very well and is much more succinct. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tim just noticed I left a line of code in the function that was from an older version, please see my edit.